# Roslyn: How do I tell if a particular assembly is referenced in a Compilation?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm writing a Roslyn diagnostic analyzer. I want to tell if `System.Collections.Immutable` is referenced in `RegisterCompilationStartAction` before I register any other actions. This is the way I'm going about it so far:

```
context.RegisterCompilationStartAction(compilationStartContext =>
{
    var compilation = compilationStartContext.Compilation;
    if (compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1") == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    ...
});
```

This works, but I don't feel it's the cleanest way to do this. Can I somehow get a `MetadataReference` corresponding to the assembly name instead and check if it's null, like `GetMetadataReference("System.Collections.Immutable") == null`? (`GetMetadataReference` doesn't accept a string, so that doesn't actually work.) If not, any other cleaner way to do this that doesn't involve picking out a particular type? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for the type you could simply search through the References and resolve the MetadataReference to check whether a specific assembly is included within a Project:

```
if(!compilation.References.Any(reference => 
        compilation.GetAssemblyOrModuleSymbol(reference)
        .Name == "System.Collections.Immutable"))
{
    return;
}
```